# cannot request READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, mediastore

I am trying to read image paths from the storage and i keep getting the SecurityException here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=31409, uid=10053 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

I am compiling against api 23 and have the permissions clearly stated in my Manifest as a direct child of my Manifest. I understand as well that the new runtime permissions state you have to ask for permission during runtime when you want to access the storage. When i write this line that would begin the check for the permission i get a cannot resolve issue in the IDE:

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
```

cannot resolve symbol Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. The only Manifest.permission that i can clearly state in my code is Manifest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE without getting a cannot resolve error. Is there something else i need to compile to have access to the other permissions in code?

Just to be clear this is the block of code that is giving me the SecurityException:

```
public List<String> getCameraImagesFull(Context context) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        String[] star = {"*"};
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, star, null, null, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                    result.add(path);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

this is the line that throws the exception:

```
cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, star, null, null, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");
```

And here are all the permissions stated in my manifest:

```
<permission
        android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

i am just wondering how i go about requesting that permission so i can get the image paths. This all works when i compile against any Lollipop build, just with the new runtime permissions on Marshmallow im getting the SecurityExeption. Any and all help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: I think you are facing this issue in Android  6.0 Marshmallow , I am also facing same issue but i am unable to request read permission for external storage, Have you find any way ?

Comment: Ok i found it from your comment below answer.

Comment: Hello Try this for API Level 23
http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> cannot resolve symbol Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

You need to add an import statement for `android.Manifest`, the same way you do with any other Java class.

> The only Manifest.permission that i can clearly state in my code is Manifest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE without getting a cannot resolve error

There is no such value (`C2D_MESSAGE`) [in `android.Manifest.permission`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html). I don't even know where there is a `Manifest` class, with a `permission` inner class, with a field named `C2D_MESSAGE`.

Comment: thank you, i see now when i was referencing Manifest.permission is was using it from my own app package vs the android package.....i can use READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as long as i state it as 'android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' vs 'Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'